# Why do some SMA connectors have a rectangular center pins?

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, coaxial

I came across an edge mount SMA connector where the soldering portion of the center pin is rectangular rather than round like normal. My initial assumption is a stronger solder joint. Any other ideas? What affect might this have on RF performance?

https://belfuse.com/resources/drawings/cinchconnectivitysolutions/johnson/dr-ccs-john-142-0701-841.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some of my own radio equipment, I found that one SMA connector has a square pin like yours. I never even noticed the different pin, and there is no noticeable difference in its performance.

I would assume it's for a stronger solder joint, as solder bonds to flat surfaces better than it does to curved surfaces, but I could be wrong, so don't quote me on it.